# Adjetivos terminados en -al y -ar

Tags: adjetivos, sufijos

El sufijo `-al` sirve para formar adjetivos a partir de sustantivos, con el significado de *referente a*. Por ejemplo:

```
principio -> principal
mundo -> mundial
```

Sin embargo, cuando el sustantivo lleva una `l`, el sufijo se convierte en `-ar`, como en:

```
lana -> lanar
alvéolo -> alveolar
```

Al menos, esa es la regla que recuerdo haber leído. Sin embargo, veo que existen muchas excepciones, como:

```
globo -> global
policía -> policial
paladar -> palatal
```

¿Existe una regla mejor que indique cuál de los dos sufijos, `-al` o `-ar`, es el correcto para formar el adjetivo?

Comment: [`-al`](https://dle.rae.es/-al) indica el DLE _En adjetivos, indica generalmente relación o pertenencia_ / _En sustantivos, indica el lugar en que abunda el primitivo._. En cuanto a [`-ar`](https://dle.rae.es/-ar) indica _En los adjetivos significa condición o pertenencia._ / _En los sustantivos indica el lugar en que abunda el primitivo._. Es decir, que en cuanto a significado viene a ser el mismo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aunque eso de cambiar el sufijo dependiendo de la letra con la que terminara la raíz (ocu*l*us -- ocu*l*ā**r**is) fue una regla en Latín, en español no existe per se: tiene más que ver con la etimología.

Los adjetivos que terminan en -ar derivan de palabras que terminaban en -āris (“relacionado con, perteneciente a”); los que terminan en -al derivan de palabras que terminaban en -ālis.

Ambos sufijos provinieron del mismo sufijo del PIE.

Según Wiktionario, bajo la sección de "-ālis":

> From Proto-Indo-European *-li-, which later dissimilated into an early version of -āris.

También enumera varias formas alternativas del sufijo: -āris, -ēlis, -īlis, -ūlis.

En cuanto a los sustantivos, los que terminan en -al «indica[n] "abundancia de" lo que significa la raíz»; y los que terminan en -ar «indican "lugar o área donde hay" lo significado por base derivativa.»

Comment: No estoy muy de acuerdo con el último párrafo. Un robledal, por ejemplo, es un lugar o área donde hay robles.

Comment: Bueno, veo como, semánticamente, una abundancia de algo y el lugar donde abunda algo podrían confundirse.  Además, no es raro que haya aberraciones en el hablar respecto a las prescripciones, o hasta las mismas descripciones, de la lengua. Y, pues, una robleda es un lugar poblado de robles, así que un robledal podría ser una abundancia de robles o un sinónimo de robleda.

Comment: La entrada "-edo/a" del DRAE: 1. suf. Forma sustantivos colectivos, en general derivados de nombres de árboles o plantas, y **designa el lugar en que abunda el primitivo**. Rosaleda, avellaneda. **Puede combinarse con -al**. Robledal, nocedal. Denotando abundancia, se combina con -ar. Polvareda, humareda